# Multiply-Controlled X Gate/MCT Gate Implementation

Tags: programming, quantum-gate, quantum-state, grovers-algorithm

I am currently trying to implement a multi-controlled Toffoli/multi-controlled X gate in Braket, but I am confused as to the general concept of cascaded X gates and other implementations. I've read Barenco, Shors, et al's work ["Elementary Gates for Quantum Computation"](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9503016), which touches on this, but it's not really illuminating the concept for me. I am partial to the V-gate method used in Barenco, as no ancillary qubits are required, but I'm open to the cascaded-X method as well. Any additional sources or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 4.3 "Controlled Operations" from [Quantum Computation and Quantum Information](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf) (linked to pdf version of the text) by Mike and Ike may provide some good additional details.

In particular, page 183 and 184 goes into details on how to implement a general implementation of $C^nX$ or $C^nU$ gate.